# Why resizing dataset images before CNN since it stretches them?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I initialize my dataset using the following function (simplified):

```
WIDTH = ...
HEIGHT = ...

def load_data(dataset_path):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for all_images:
        image = cv2.imread(pimage_path)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (WIDTH, HEIGHT)) #???
        labels.add(corresponding_label)
    return (np.array(images).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3) / 255, np.array(labels))
```

In the tutorials I watched, people resize the input images to (WIDTH, HEIGHT). But this proceeds to stretch the images. I don't understand why we have to do that, because in the model I'm using the input images are applied a convolution. So I tried to not resize the input images but I got an error during the reshape process at the end of my function.

What am I missing?

Comment: You first need to resize the image using `PIL` or `cv2` and then convert it to a NumPy array. Reshaping a NumPy array won't work as the number of elements might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't limited to stretching the image, perhaps you could either crop the image or add a bufferzone with a consistent color, although if you can afford to crop the images that'd be more convenient but still you can just fill the rest of the space with a fixed color, the model would not care less.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of error did you get when reshaping? Chances are that if you do not reshape the image you cannot later on resize the numpy array to WIDTH, HEIGHT. In that case, you must change the value of WIDTH and HEIGHT.